# Split  String at the first five <br />'s with php

Tags: php

```
<?php

$text = <<<EOT

<br /> 1  <br /> 2 <br />  3  <br /> 4 <br /> 5  <br /> 6 
<br /> 7  <br /> 8 <br />  9  <br /> 10 <br /> 11  <br /> 12 
<br /> 13  <br /> 14 <br />  15  <br /> 16 <br /> 17  <br /> 18 

EOT;
?>
```

I want split $txt and result

```
$txt="
<br /> 1  <br /> 2 <br />  3  <br /> 4 <br /> 5 ";
```

I want split position 5 of `<br />`

1,2,3,4 is random string
Please help me

Comment: What's the criterion for splitting?

Comment: I want split position 5 of <br />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array_splice(explode('<br />',$text),0,6);  
$result = implode('<br />',$arr);
```

[Working link](http://www.ideone.com/cF9m2)